# How escape a "{" and a "}" in Inno Setup

Tags: escaping, registry, inno-setup

How can I escape the characters `{` and `}` in Inno Setup, the characters are used in the `[Registry]` section?

`{`, `"{"` do not compile.

`%7d`, `"%7d"`, `{%7d}` all compile, but do not work, they result in the wrong values in the registry.

Best regards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can escape the `{` by doubling it. There is no need to escape the `}` as it is only used if inside a constant.

From the [help file](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm):

> A "{" character is treated as the start of the constant. If you want to use that actual character in a place where constants are supported, you must use two consecutive "{" characters. (You do not need to double "}" characters.)

Comment: Thanks, its so easy. I think i missed this part of the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to escape a quotation mark ("). Doubling it does not escape this,

I was able to force the hex-code by using `{%|%22}`.

On http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts this escaping is show as `{%NAME|DefaultValue}`. Leaving `NAME` empty makes it use the hex code.

Comment: That does not answer the posted question.