# INNO Setup registry keys with braces

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to change the values of registry keys that contain braces.

Here's the code:

```
 [Registry]
 Root: HKCU; Subkey:"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group \
 Policy Objects\{{8040B178-46A6-4531-85A5-797EE99EA211}} \
 Machine\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"; ValueType: \
 dword; ValueName:"BranchReadinessLevel"; ValueData: 32; Permissions: \
 users-modify; Components: APC Classic Workstation;
```

During compiling the system recommended that I change `{` to `{{` (which I did). However, I read another article that said to replace the closing `}` with `%7d` - I tried that. Nothing seems to work.

All registry edits that do not have braces work fine.

Comment: I thought that only the opening `{` needed to be escaped by using `{{` but not the closing `}` brace.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800425/how-escape-a-and-a-in-inno-setup

Comment: SOLVED: Thank you Andrew... escaping the opening {{ and using a single } to close worked perfectly.